# Something deletes the cursor line when booting into the console

Tags: command-line

I configured a grub menu item in Ubuntu 18.04 to boot right into the text console.

I see the prompt. Then a few seconds later, the prompt is erased and the cursor moves to the beginning of the line. I can press enter and the prompt appears again. However, when I edit a file right after startup, it also deletes the cursor line. It's like something's running in the background, deleting the current cursor line.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this issue?

Update: Meanwhile I've done more tests and can confirm that the issue doesn't have anything to do with the startup mode text vs graphics. It also happens when I startup seeing a high resolution / microfiche boot menu and just add 3 to the kernel command line in grub.

I'm only guessing, but it might be some systemd or security stuff initializing at startup. Maybe Ubuntu isn't worthwhile anymore. Who makes all these silly decisions not testing/breaking Linux fundamental features? Too fancy.

Update2. It's also happening in startup mode 1. I also tried disabling all the profile and bash startup scripts, as well as configuring autologin (getty -a root) - but no change.

Update3. There're less processes (ps -eLf) before and after the problem occurs, so it might be something in the late startup process, but I don't see anything out of the ordinary. I reinstalled a new Minimal Desktop system to see if I can reproduce the issue. Doing some more tests including the 5.4 and previous 4.18 kernel I can say that the problem isn't related to GRUB_TERMINAL="console" or nomodeset, or autologin. Simply go into the Grub menu and replace quiet splash vt_handoff with the number 3 to see the problem. Unlike in my original configuration, however, it doesn't erase the line, but the cursor still moves to pos 1, about 15 seconds after startup, regardless of being at the prompt or in a text editor. Something is shooting my screen.

```
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS gpudiag-Z270N-WIFI tty1
<- Cursor moved here_ in:
```

And btw, the problem also occurs when I switch to tty2 (alt-F2) right after startup.

Meanwhile I also found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341658/ttys-cursor-moves-to-wrong-position-during-login

Update4: systemd-fsckd.service was indeed the culprit. However, I decided to do a different approach since I don't want to wait for the service to finish before accessing the console. From what I figure reading the man page of systemd-fsckd, it receives messages about file system check progress from fsck through an UNIX domain socket. I don't need that, so I simply disabled the service adding the following to the kernel command line in grub:

```
systemd.mask=systemd-fsckd.socket systemd.mask=systemd-fsckd.serivce
```

Since this is only temporary, affecting a particular grub console kernel/boot option and does not affect the system overall, I prefer this solution.

Comment: Interesting link, but I'm using GRUB_TERMINAL="console" and boot the system in MBR legacy mode. The reason for all this because I need to use a program that doesn't work with any framebuffer, hence the BIOS VGA character console. I also use nomodeset and nouveau.modeset=0 because I must not use any graphics driver. I don't need any fancy boot screen, but I need to boot from different kernels, one for a text only console and the other for standard Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: I understand. I can't easily revert everything I've done, like modifying pam to disable the fancy motd at startup, etc. but otherwise it's a plain vanilla system. I haven't changed anything profile related. It's not happening via ssh. It's just something that appears on the console right after startup using startup level 3. I'm also able to reproduce in standard graphics mode, hence it does not seem to have anything to do with grub or the video driver.

Comment: Sorry, but using a different software that doesn't require a BIOS text console isn't the solution, and also not possible. It's proprietary software to test graphics adapters and it's not involved in the startup process and hence not the cause of the issue.

Comment: I know about Ubuntu server - I'm a sysadmin using Linux for over 30 years. Please don't suggest a work-around using a different system. I don't want to use a different partition or machine just for running a special piece of software.

Comment: `tput reset` + Enter?

Comment: It doesn't clear the screen. It only moves the cursor to the beginning of the line and erases the line - I can see that also happening in a text editor. It only does it once, about 15 seconds after system startup after the prompt appears, hence erasing the prompt, or whatever is on the screen.

Comment: I'd expect `tput reset` to restore the console to a sane default, i.e. make the the cursor reappear among other things.

Comment: A tput reset isn't happening because it doesn't clear the screen. They're also no jobs running in the background. Also disabled dbus.service in grub temporarily, which in turn disabled many other hardware startups, however, problem persists.

Comment: I assume "isn't happening" means; "does nothing useful". *shrug*. From what I see here I conclude that you have some kind of software launching 15 seconds after starting an initial shell (by autologin). Anything in the /var/log/ files indicated as starting late (15 seconds)?

Comment: No software launching after startup. Isn't happening means it doesn't clear the screen. tpu reset does not just erase the line but clears the complete screen. I've added some more findings, please see Update3 in my original post.

Comment: Problem solved. please see update4.

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for sharing your solution :-) Please create an own 'answer', and when possible (maybe after a couple of days) 'accept' it. This will help other users that are affected by the same issue. If you can spend even more energy for our community, please create a bug report at Launchpad.

Comment: I'm not yet convinced whether or not systemd-fsckd is causing or exploiting the issue. Apparently it moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, while in other configurations it also erases the line. While this may seem like a cosmetic issue to some, breaking the login input mask, or erasing the cursor line while in a text editor is quite annoying. I'll have to think about it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently **systemd-fsckd.service** is causing or exploiting the issue when starting the system as level 3 (command console).

It might be OK to wait 15 seconds after system startup before doing anything at the command line, but I decided to temporarily stop the service from starting by adding the following to the Grub Kernel command line:

```
systemd.mask=systemd-fsckd.socket systemd.mask=systemd-fsckd.serivce
```

As I understand from reading the man(8) page of systemd-fsckd.service, it conveys messages about file system check progress from fsck through an UNIX domain socket. I don't need it.

Comment: +1+1; Congratulations for finding a solution and thanks for sharing it :-)